# AWS lambda unable to find aws-sdk module

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

To reduce the serverless package size I am trying to exclude aws-sdk from being included with deployment.

I was under the impression that the aws-sdk npm package was included by default in the aws lambda runtime. When I make a new function this looks to be the case, I can console log the aws-sdk version just fine.

When my larger lambda, uploaded with serverless, is executed it comes back with a an import error for not finding aws-sdk

```
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'
```

The lambda is using runtime nodejs12.x

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please reference the AWS doc that states this is best practice?

Comment: That's indeed not expected behavior.  Can you maybe post a snippet of the code that produces the error? Both the node and the lambda part of the SAM template? Thanks!